# Change content of $page['content'] variable

Tags: users, nodes, forms, 7

I have overwritten my login page with a file named `page--user--login.tpl.php`. Now I have this:

```
<div class="main-container container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <section<?php print $content_column_class; ?>>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
        <h1>Xmed.be Stocksolutions</h1>
        <p>"We help you Xchange your stock"</p>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($page['help'])): ?>
        <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (!empty($action_links)): ?>
        <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <a href="user/register">NO ACCOUNT? REGISTER</a>
      <a href="user/password">FORGOT PASSWORD?</a>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I added two links at the end (register and password). But I would like them to be inside $page['content'], so that they are in the section. How can I edit the $content variable, loop through it or something?

UPDATE:

Now I've added in my template.php:

```
function hook_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    var_dump('test');
}
```

But I'm not getting test around my form (also looked in html).

I've also already tried:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm($form);
}
```

But no result or something ...

Comment: You mean $page['content'], not $content...

Comment: yes, sorry. Changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [hook_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) to add them into the content array:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_page_alter(&$page) {

  // Check if this is the correct page.
  if(!isset($page['content']['system_main']['#form_id']) || $page['content']['system_main']['#form_id'] != 'user_login') return;

  // Add links.
  $page['content']['system_main']['register'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<p><a href="user/register">NO ACCOUNT? REGISTER</a></p>',
    '#weight' => 20
  );
  $page['content']['system_main']['password'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<p><a href="user/password">FORGOT PASSWORD?</a></p>',
    '#weight' => 21
  );

}
```

Another option here would be to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) instead. Although [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) may well be the most efficient option as it will only run for this specific form removing any overhead from other pages.

Comment: And I add this in my template.php from my subtheme?

Comment: Yes, I think you can add any alter hook in template.php.

Comment: I've updated my begin topic ..

Comment: Replace the work hook with your theme name.

Comment: Maybe read [Understanding the hook system for Drupal modules](https://drupal.org/node/292) and [Drupal Hooks Explained](http://www.wintercreative.com/blog/2014/04/07/drupal-hooks-explained.html) or maybe even [A Very Introduction to Drupal's hook_form_alter()](http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter)